# How to add a tag to scriptmethod so that it can be excluded/included based on tag?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to execute all the scriptmethods in my code. But few script methods should be excluded from it.

```
function new-TestSuite {
$testsuite = [pscustomobject]@{

    Data1 = 'value1'
    Data2 = 'value2'

}

$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name Testcase1 -Value { "Testcase 1" <# Code using Data1 #> }
$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name TestCase2 -Value { "TestCase2" <# Code using Data2 #> }
$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name teardown -Value { "teardown" <# Code using Data2 #> }
$testsuite | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name setup -Value { "setup" <# Code using Data2 #> }

$testsuite
}

function Invoke-Testcase
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        $Testsuite,
        $testcase =$null,
        $Exclude = @("TearDown","Setup")
    )    
    if($Testsuite -eq $null)
    {
        throw "Test suite is null"
    }

    if($null -eq $testcase)
    {
        $ScriptMethods = $Testsuite.psobject.Methods | Where {$_ -is [psscriptmethod]} #| Foreach Invoke

        foreach($sm in $ScriptMethods)
        {
            if(-not ($Exclude -contains $sm.name))
            {
                $sm.Invoke() 
            }
            else
            {
                Write-verbose "scriptmethod $($sm.name) will not be executed as it is in exclude list"
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($tc in $testcase)
        {
            $Testsuite.psobject.Methods | Where {$_ -is [psscriptmethod] -And $_.Name -eq $tc } | foreach Invoke
        }
    }
}

Set-Alias -Name InvokeTestCase -Value Invoke-Testcase

$ts = new-TestSuite
InvokeTestcase $ts -verbose

InvokeTestcase $ts teardown
```

In the above function (Invoke-Testcase) i am using exclude list and achieve it. But if any new method need not to be executed then excludelist has to be updated.

Instead of it if there is a tag can be added into scriptmethod property it will have more control to include/exclude. Is there any way to create a tag for scriptmethod?

Comment: Are you sure this is the smallest possible question you are asking? Most of the question seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why not change from an exclusion list to an _inclusion_ list?

Comment: @gvee Inclusion list will more frequently change than exclude list

Comment: Let's say there is something you can add to the scriptmethod... you'll have to change _that_ just as often as your inclusion/exclusion list! I think you need to think about _what_ you're asking for and _why_ a little more.